# What's equivalent to javascript bubbling events in .NET?

Tags: .net

I think Javascript has a mechanism that allows to bubbling events from top down and down up. What's the equivalent in .NET WINFORM (not ASP.NET) ?

Events/Delegates in .NET automates the Observer/Design Pattern by avoiding the subject to handle the message update sending to subscribers so I can't see any fundamental reason why bubling couldn't have existed.

Events/Delegates allows loose coupling compared to using IObserver, in the same way if bubbling was implemented it would also allow loose coupling instead of doing inheritance and hard-wire the call to the base parent.

Comment: Right I meant Event Handling System for Winform or pure .net core system.

Answer (score 2):

This has *very* little to do with JavaScript, bubbling is a property of the DOM.  Which represents documents in a tree-like hierarchy, making it natural to pass events that are not handled up the tree.

This doesn't nearly correspond as well in a window hierarchy.  Chief problem being that if you nest windows deeply then you'd have been yourself a dog of a program that takes forever to draw the UI.  Nevertheless, the default window procedure *does* bubble window messages to the parent.  This is selective behavior, it depends on the particular message.  A WM_MOUSEWHEEL message for example bubbles, looking for a parent window that knows how to scroll the view.  But WM_LBUTTONDOWN does not bubble, the parent window wouldn't normally have much use for a mouse click on an area that it doesn't 'own'.  Other than perhaps to set the focus to the control, something that already happens automatically.

You can certainly make it bubble yourself, just send the message to the parent.  In effect this already happens.  A control normally generates a MouseDown or Click event.  Which is subscribed by an event handler in the form.  Different model, same effect.

Comment: "Chief problem being that if you nest windows deeply then you'd have been yourself a dog of a program that takes forever to draw the UI." Why would it take forever for Winform and not for DOM :) If the choice is dependant on the way Win32 works because at the end .net winform just sits above I may understand but I'd like really to have rational crystal clear reason.

Comment: A window is a very expensive system object.  There's *lot's* of functionality built-in, with reams of appcompat code.  This doesn't come for free.  Browsers don't use windows to render the DOM elements.  Same thing with WPF.  To see where this matters, ask a web programmer what luck he's having making his pages work on all browsers.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this is more of a DOM property than an ECMAScript core property. (That said, 99% of use cases of Javascript are in DOM related scenarios like the browser)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing. If you want to pass the event along to your parent, use the sender parameter to your event, cast it to a `Control`, call the `Parent` method, and fire the event there.

That said, you probably *shouldn't* do this. The .NET platform is not Javascript. When in Rome, do as the romans do.

Really, events in .NET are nothing like Javascript events at all... they are merely a list of delegates. Raising the event results in all of the delegates being called. Events can be placed on all objects, not only GUI objects. Therefore it would make no sense to define them as solely a GUI concept.

Comment: Bubling is an automatic mechanism, using sender is not automatic. I do know .NET is not Javascript :) that doesn't mean that Bubling as a concept should not exist. A concept is independant from languages.

Comment: Events/Delegates in .NET automates the Observer/Design Pattern by avoiding the subject to handle the message update sending to subscribers so there's no fundamental reason why bubling couldn't have existed.

Comment: @user: Perhaps, but the concept is inherently tied to Javascript's role as a GUI only programming language, while .NET's events were designed to be much more general creatures, useful for much more than simply waiting for things like button presses. .NET events are much more general. I'm not saying bubbling should not exist, I'm saying bubbling does not exist. .NET doesn't have anything like Javascript's events, just as Javascript has nothing like .NET's events. Just because they are called the same thing doesn't mean they are remotely used for the same kinds of tasks.

Comment: @user: Since when does the observer pattern mention anything about bubbling?

Comment: I didn't say that observer pattern has to do with bubling. I say that event handler AUTOMATES observer pattern. Event handling by itself doesn't mean bubling.

Comment: I never said that, I said Event / Delegates has to do with Observer Pattern. It's about automation and loose coupling Bubbling allows the same kind of thing.

Comment: Bubling is not tight to Javascript since MSDN talk about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(VS.71).aspx but why didn't they implement this for winform ?

Comment: @user: They didn't implement it there. ASP.NET is built on top of Javascript, which performs the actual bubbling. Bubbling has nothing to do with lose coupling. It's specifically related to JS's event model. No other language of which I am aware has anything like Javascript's event bubbling.

Comment: Objective C has it and it isn't Web, it's Iphone.

Comment: With Bubbling or Event Hooking system one can do what AOP does but much more naturally without linking to some alien plumbing.

Comment: @user: No, Objective C does not have it, the API provided specifically by the iPhone does. Out of the box Objective C provides no such facility.